# ASP.NET MVC3 - Data Annotations with EF Database First (ObjectContext, DbContext)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

How can we use Data Annotations for models if the models are generated with 4.1 ADO.NET DbContext Generator or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [partial metadata class](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)