# asp.net mvc: thousand separator for int value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, int, separator

I have a price field in my database as integer
now i pass my model to view and show the price in view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
```

How can i put thousand separator for price in view?
tnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply the `DisplayFormat` attribute to your model property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
```

Then the formatting is done by the ModelBinder for you instead of you having to remember to do it in each individual view.

Comment: @Morika See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956081/asp-net-mvc3-data-annotations-with-ef-database-first-objectconext-dbcontext

Comment: When I try to do this with @Html.InputFor helper, I get an error on the client that says 'The specified value "$12,345" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.'  What is the recommended way to show comma separated thousands in an input control?

Answer (score 5):

Here ...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price.ToString("n2"))
```

Comment: Error: no overload for method ToString takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Morika - If the data type of `price` is `int`, there is no problem with that : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx